# Angular Flex-layout 2 columns full height or Adjustable content

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mkLk.png)

I'm trying to make this layout stay with the full height of the window or the internal content. But I never can.
Below is my code and I do not know where I might be wrong.
I know it might not be the right place, but could anyone help me?

```
<!-- FLEX-CONTAINER - WRAP - INLINE STYLES FOR CORRECTION -->
<div fxLayout="row nowrap" fxFlexFill fxLayoutAlign="start stretch">

  <!-- FLEX-CHILD - LEFT -->
  <div id="login-information" fxFlex="1 1" fxFlexFill>
    <div style="height: 850px; width: 300px; background-color: red;"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- FLEX-CHILD - RIGHT -->
  <div id="login-form" fxFlex="1 1" fxFlexFill>
    <div style="height: 900px; width: 300px; background-color: green;"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: is this single component or top level app.component? where are those blue elements from your image ? Have you tried this: https://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/gpard ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flex-layout-seed-qjmv1k?file=app%2Ftest.component.css

Comment: Remove `height: 100%;` from test.component.css